# interactively edit emacs variable in buffer

Tags: variables

I was looking at
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107243/centering-display-equations-with-org-latex-preview)
on StackOverflow and was wondering if there was a nice way built-in to
edit strings of text stored in variables as if they were buffers? `M-x set-variable` doesn't really cut it when you have a long string of LaTeX options inside a variable.

I'm looking for behavior similar to the package [string-edit](https://github.com/magnars/string-edit.el), but in order to edit emacs variables.

Comment: I'm envisioning something along the lines of string-edit but which recognizes variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "recognizes variables"?

Comment: If you download string-edit from melpa, you'll see how that lets you edit a string as if it were in its own separate buffer. I'd like to (edit-variable-at-point) and have it bring up a buffer containing a representation of the contents of the variable, especially if that variable is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining [`string-edit`](https://github.com/magnars/string-edit.el) with a bit of custom elisp can provide the feature you
want. For example, the function below will enable you to edit the value of a
variable in `string-edit-mode`, provided that this variable is string-valued.

```
(defun my/edit-string-variable-at-point ()
  "If the symbol at point is a string-valued variable, update it
using `string-edit' to provide the new value."
  (interactive)
  (let ((variable (intern (thing-at-point 'symbol t))))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*edit-variable*")
      (erase-buffer)
      (print `(setq ,variable ,(symbol-value variable))
             (current-buffer))
      (goto-char (- (point-max) 3))
      (if (string-edit-at-point)
          ;; Variable value is a string
          ;; Overrides C-c C-c so that the new value is evaluated after `string-edit-conclude'
          (let ((oldmap (cdr (assoc 'string-edit-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
                (newmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
            (set-keymap-parent newmap oldmap)
            (define-key newmap (kbd "C-c C-c")
              #'(lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (string-edit-conclude)
                  (eval-buffer)
                  (kill-buffer)))
            (make-local-variable 'minor-mode-overriding-map-alist)
            (push `(string-edit-mode . ,newmap) minor-mode-overriding-map-alist))
        ;; Variable value was not a string
        (message "`%s' is not a string!" variable)
        (kill-buffer)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

If they are user options, then `M-x customize-option`.

If they are defvars, not options, then edit the value in the source buffer or in a copy of the defvar in another buffer.

Or use `M-: (setq THE-VAR "edit the text in the minibuffer)`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `*scratch*` buffer and create a template `(setq var-name '...)`.  Now type `C-h v var-name`.  Use `M-w` to copy the value, then yank it into the `*scratch*` buffer, replacing the `...`.  Edit to your heart's content, then go to the end of the buffer and `C-x C-e` (`eval-last-sexp`).

I'm not actually familiar with `string-edit`, so this may not be what you hoped for.  I just needed to edit a large variable and wanted to do it without having to futz around with installing packages.  This works.